# error TS2749: 'IRequestWithUser' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof IRequestWithUser'?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am extending `Request` in `express` library to contain a user property:

```
import { Request } from 'express';

export default interface RequestWithUser extends Request {
  user: {
    user_name: string;
    password: string;
  }
}
```

The title error appears in the first parameter annotation:

```
import IRequestWithUser from '../shared/interfaces/isRequestWithUser';

const router: Router = Router();

router.post('/myRoute', async (req: IRequestWithUser, res: Response) => {

/*
error TS2749: 'IRequestWithUser' refers to a value, 
but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 
'typeof IRequestWithUser'?
*/
```

I don't believe interfaces are values. They should purely be types. So what is causing this error?

**Also tried**

`typeof IRequestWithUser` This results in `No overload matches this call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there's something missing from your code snippets, but the only error I get on Typescript 3.9 is one that relates to the overload error that you allude to later in your question.

Because the `.post()` call is looking for a callback that expects type `Request`, you can't type your `req` argument as `IRequestWithUser`. This is because, although `IRequestWithUser` will contain all properties of `Request`, the Typescript compiler can't guarantee that the extra properties you plan to have in `req` will be there when the callback is run.

The [recommended way](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L17) to extend Express types is to use [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces). This allows you to "redefine" the `Request` type altogether, but it's a global definition so it gets messy:

```js
// definitions/express/index.d.ts
import * as express from 'express' // Unfortunately, you need some kind of import here to make this a valid module.

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
    export interface Request {
        user: {
            user_name: string;
            password: string;
        }
    }
}
```

Your compiler should pick this file up on its own and support your new property using the original `Request` type. You might need to have an explicit `typeRoots` set in your `tsconfig.json` if you're using something like `ts-node` though.